# pandas adding new rows to dataframe based on dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas

I have transactional data for users as follows:

```
userid accountid weeknumber amount_spent
1      a         1          100
1      a         2          200
1      a         4          500
1      b         1          500
...
9      z         1          350
```

The data only captured weeks where the user had transactions. I need to go through the data and add rows for when the user didn't spend any money.

E.g. I need to add rows like:

```
userid accountid weeknumber amount_spent
1      a         3          0
```

Currently I do it as follows:

```
# get all user-account pairs
for user_acct_pair in df.groupby(['userid', 'accountid']).groups.iterkeys():
    userid = user_acct_pair[0]
    acctid = user_acct_pair[1]

# get the weeks that we have recorded for this user
weeks_recorded = df.xs((userid, acctid), axis=0, level=[0, 1], \
                              drop_level=True).index.values

for i in range(1, MAX_WEEK_NUMBER):
    if i not in weeks_recorded:
        # add the row for the week without transactions
        df.loc[(userid, acctid, i), 'amount_spent'] = 0

# convert back to df from groupby object
df = df.reset_index()
```

This seems to be incredibly slow when I run on a dataset with ~90,000 rows. 
I think that there is a high cost in finding a row in a multilevel index when the row doesn't exist yet.

Are there more efficient ways to do this, or perhaps built in functionalities to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why would you do that? Effectively, the data you want to add is already there, by the fact that it is absent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would forget groupby and iterating through the dataframe. I would just create a dataframe that looks like the empty rows you want, and then merge in the data that is populated.

```
#create your existing data
df = pd.DataFrame({'userId'    : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2], 
                   'accountId' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'z'],
                   'week'            : [1, 2, 4, 1, 1],
                   'amount'    : [100, 200, 500, 500, 350]})

#create unique ID pairs
unique_ids = set(zip(df['userId'], df['accountId']))

#create empty data frame
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'userId'    :  np.repeat([val[0] for val in unique_ids], 5),
                       'accountId' :  np.repeat([val[1] for val in unique_ids], 5),
                       'week'      :  np.tile(list(range(1, 6)), len(unique_ids))})

#merge
pd.merge(df, new_df, how = 'outer').sort_values(['accountId', 'userId', 'week']).fillna(0)
```

This is for a 5 week period. The result is:

```
   accountId  amount  userId  week
0          a   100.0       1     1
1          a   200.0       1     2
5          a     0.0       1     3
2          a   500.0       1     4
6          a     0.0       1     5
3          b   500.0       1     1
11         b     0.0       1     2
12         b     0.0       1     3
13         b     0.0       1     4
14         b     0.0       1     5
4          z   350.0       2     1
7          z     0.0       2     2
8          z     0.0       2     3
9          z     0.0       2     4
10         z     0.0       2     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution :

```
#Grouby accountid
for i in df.groupby(['userid', 'accountid']).max().itertuples():
    print(i)
    #Get range of weeks
    r = [i for i in range(1,i.weeknumber+1)]
    #find all unique weeks
    unique = df[(df.accountid == i.Index[1]) & (df.userid == i.Index[0])].weeknumber.unique()
    #Substract the one that are already here
    missing = [e for e in r if e not in unique]
    #append them to the dataframe
    for m in missing:
        line = pd.DataFrame({'userid':[i.Index[0]],"weeknumber":[m], "amount_spent":[0], "accountid":i.Index[1]})
        df = df.append(line)
```

Should be faster, but on small sample it's hard to tell